# When to call scrollIntoView()

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I have googled, searched forums and stack exchange but nothing seems to work for me. I am running extJS 3.2.1.

Basically I have a gridpanel control which has items that are greyed out as they are completed but the vertical view pane is only about 200 px while the list can grow quite large leaving users to scroll down each time I do a store.reload()

I have discovered I can manually move the next item in the list by calling:

grid.getView().getRow(15).scrollIntoView();

I cannot use selectRow() because I have enabled the checkboxes instead of row selection.

Anyway the above code works great only I cannot determine "where" to call it. I have tried capturing the store.load event as well as the grid.afterrender and neither seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the source of `store.reload();` you can see it calls the the load method. 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/source/Store.html#Ext-data-Store-method-reload

So you really should be hooking the load event.

Something like

```
store.on('load',function(){
    grid.getView().getRow(15).scrollIntoView();

})
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel-method-select
is the cell selection model equivalent btw ( of row select ).